# Как выводить время сервера, а не время, которое у пользователя на устройстве?

Tags: java, дата, время, simpledateformat

Использую такой вот код, позволяющий добавить дату и время, к сообщению пользователя, который его написал:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Message {

    //поле
    private String text;
    public String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());
public String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
    //пустой конструктор (необходим для работы базы данных)
    public Message() {
    }

    //Конструктор используемый нами
    public Message(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        setText(date + " в " + time + "\n" + this.text +"\n");
    }

    //геттер
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    //сеттер
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы отправляемое время было серверное, а не то, что у пользователя на устройстве. Иначе получается так, что время сообщений показывается не совсем правильное, потому что все находятся в разных часовых поясах и т.д..

PS: код главного активити:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //1. Пользовательский интерфейс (UI)
    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;


    //2. Firebase
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessageDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 3. Связываем UI
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // 4. Инициализируем Firebase
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mMessageDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");

        // 5. Создаем слушатель базы данных
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override


           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        // 6. Устанавливаем слушатель базы данных
        mMessageDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }

    // 7. Создаем лист где мы будем хранить сообщение
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    // 8. Создаем и устанавливаем адаптер для сообщений
    mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, messages);
    mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

    // 9. Устанавливаем слушатель клика на кнопку, создаем сообщение, отправляем сообщение в базу, удаляем текст
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Message message = new Message(mMessageEditText.getText().toString());
            mMessageDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });

    // *Устанавливаем слушатель текста
    mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}

    // 10.Удаляем слушатель базы данных
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mChildEventListener != null) {
            mMessageDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
            mChildEventListener = null;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Так ведь пользователю нужно видеть время отправления сообщения, которое соответствует именно его часовому поясу.

Одним из решений является хранение времени на сервере в UTC. Пусть сервер, при получении сообщения, выставляет ему свое время (timestamp в UTC), и возвращает его отправителю в качестве ответа. Клиент всегда, получив историю сообщений или входящее сообщение, конвертирует из UTC-0 в свой часовой пояс.

Тогда на сервере время будет единое, а клиенты будут одно и то же время отображать у себя в нужном часовом поясе.

Comment: и каким же образом это сделать? чат работает на Firebase

Comment: Тут уже не подскажу. Реализовывал сервер своими руками. Но, насколько я знаю, у Firebase есть возможность добавлять код разработчика, расширяя функционал.

Comment: просто я примерно понимаю о чём идёт речь.. Нужно каким-то образом откуда-то брать единое время сервера, допустим в момент отправки сообщения получить время "22:10" и добавить его к сообщению. А то я сейчас зашел с двух телефонов в чат, и в истории сообщений вижу как два сообщения отправленные в одно и то же время, отображают в итоге разное время..

Comment: время единое должен выставлять сервер, а клиент, пока сервер не ответил на отправку, показывает свое время. Если сервер будет выставлять время и раздавать его клиентам, то как раз и будет все едино

Comment: Мне даже не обязательно конвертировать что то в свой часовой пояс. достаточно будет сделать так, чтоб оно всегда было московским допустим. независимо от времени у пользователя в телефоне и за "окном"

Comment: То есть пользователь сидит где-то во Владивостоке, отправляет сообщение в 18:00, а у него отображается, будто он отправил в 11:00?

Comment: ну если смысл чата в том, чтоб просто оставить свой отзыв, а не переписываться в нём три часа, то я думаю ничего страшного не случится от этого))

Comment: Дело Ваше, но такие мелочи отпугивают пользователей, хоть и кажутся незначительными.

Comment: хотя я думаю если учитывать этот факт, то можно время вообще не использовать в чате) ,т.к время совсем и не нужно впринципе знать)

Comment: дата и сообщение. вполне стандартный шаблон для моей идеи

Comment: Показывать то может и не нужно, но сортировать сообщения каким-то образом ведь надо. А если будет разница в часовых поясах и клиент будет сам выставлять время, то порядок сообщений будет разный на устройствах с разными часовыми поясами

Comment: не будет разный порядок) в xml разметке параметр указан, из за которого все новые сообщения внизу списка оказываются.

Comment: А получение истории?

Comment: еще не добавлял кучу сообщений, чтоб проверить, как будет., но по моему сообщения не подгружаются, а грузится вся база..